# Help with setting up Kinect

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to the ROS Community and am trying to connect a Kinect camera with ROS for my current project. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and the ROS indigo distribution.

So far, I have followed the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/evarobot/Tutorials/indigo/Kinect. However towards the end of the tutorial, after the step `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`, I get a the following warnings:

```
----------
[ WARN] [1471581084.378448573]: Camera calibration file /home/fday562/.ros/camera_info/rgb_B00364629578138B.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1471581084.378476614]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1471581084.378506677]: Camera calibration file /home/fday562/.ros/camera_info/depth_B00364629578138B.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1471581084.378520480]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
----------
```

Everything else works fine. Earlier I was trying to use usb_cam and it threw similar warnings. Any idea whats this about? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242016/help-with-setting-up-kinect/) by [dexter05](https://answers.ros.org/users/27787/dexter05/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem with my ASUS Xtion Pro Live camera, and answered my own question here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/238725/openni-camera-calibration-yaml-file-not-found/#241384
I used this http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration calibration to generate those files.

---

Originally posted by [fleishman](https://answers.ros.org/users/27385/fleishman/) with karma: 56 on 2016-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0